# One Firebase Project - Multiple apps using Twitter auth

Tags: ios, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase project that will contain many apps, all sharing the same database, users, etc..

My requirement is to use the same authentication/login across all applications. For example, if the user authenticates using Facebook or Twitter in App#1, then they can use that same authentication to log into App#2, etc..

I know Firebase only allows 1 Facebook app per project, so I have worked around that.

So I guess my simple question is, does Firebase also only allow 1 Twitter application per project? I cannot find any documentation specifying either way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each Firebase project, you can configure only one provider (Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc) in the Sign-in method subsection. Notice in the Firebase Console, you can only add one client/secret per provider. If you have multiple mobile applications, they can use the same configured providers across. However, you can't have multiple OAuth clients for the same provider.